# The recreated columns in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a windows form. I defined 5 columns for this DataGridView dgv.

The datatable returned by a stored procedure is bound with this DataGridView.

```
         DataTable table1 = returned by a stored procedure in C#;
         dgv.DataSource = table1;
         dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
         dgv = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
```

Then in another button event. I want to rebind the DataGridView a data source.

```
      DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
```

Then

```
 DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["Interval"] = txtBox1.Text;
            dr["Count"] = txtBox2.Text;
            dr["AgeBegin"] = txtBox3.Text;
            dr["AgeEnd"] = txtBox4.Text;
            dr["Gender"] = txtBox5.Text;
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
            dgv.DataSource = dt1;
```

dt1 only have one row. Now dgv displays 10 columns. The first 5 columns are empty, the last 5 columns have real data.

Why? Thanks.

Comment: What are the headers for those columns?  Do they match your headers?

Comment: Try setting the DataPropertyName

Comment: @K'Leg, The columns are same but the headtext are little different.

Comment: "dgv = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;"  this line does not compile.

Comment: Try what SwDevMan81 suggested, It does make sense.

Comment: I have tested this and doing exactly what you are doing I can't duplicate the problem, I even removed the auto generate columns, and still I only get 5.  Are you predefining the columns in your datagridview?  I would suggest leaving it blank to start and allow the Autogenerate columns, at least until you figure out the flaw

Comment: Now it seems only has 5 cloumns but empty data. I have predefined the headtext for the columns by the smart tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagridviews automatically add rows on you if there is no spot to put the data.  Unless you tell it not to, which is not an option in the designer.

```
dgv.AutoGenerateColumns=false;
```

nevermind you have this already.

You shouldn't have to but have you tried clearing the dgv before rebinding it, just to try to find the problem?

Are you predefining the columns in your datagridview? I would suggest leaving it blank to start and allow the Autogenerate columns, at least until you figure out the flaw

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` **before** you assign it to the `DataSource`

```
DataTable table1 = returned by a stored procedure in C#;
dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false; // Before assigning the DataSource
dgv.DataSource = table1;
...
```

Comment: that would make sense, but it is when he changes the datasource the the problem arises